# On connection weights in an Artificial Neural Network

Tags: neural-networks

I play a lot with [PyBrain](http://pybrain.org) -- Artificial Neural Network implementation in Python. I have noticed that in all the models that I receive the weights of the connections are roughly normally distributed around zero with a pretty low standard deviation (~0.3), which means that they are effectively limited within the [-1, 1] range. What does this mean? Is it a requirement of ANN? An outcome of backpropagaion learning? A sign for network health? Or just a random observation?

[image]

Comment: Interesting. How do you initialize the weights? Uniformly, Normal, ... ?

Comment: Are these actually normal (using some kind of normality test), or do you just refer to the fact that it's bell-shaped? I would actually have expected some kind of heavy-tailed distribution. Additional information which would be helpful is network structure -- how many layers, units, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just took a look at some of my neural networks; the weights in those look normally distributed.

One possible argument is that each weight is the sum of IID delta values during backpropagation, so they will be Gaussian (due to the central limit theorem). This argument involves making some simplifications; for example the summed deltas are probably not independent of each other during backpropagation.

Answer (score 1):

I poked around a little in the PyBrain source and noticed that some parameters are, if not otherwise given, set to normally distributed random values with mean=0 and standard deviation=1.

I would guess that training tends to pulls a lot of connection weights down to zero (for non-informative features) and pushes a few away (for the informative ones), but that's just speculation. It would be cool to see a plot of feature kurotsis vs. training time; I might try that some rainy day if you don't get to it first...